# Is there a way to convert numbers,brackets etc to string type without using str in python?

Tags: python, string

for example
converting (5) to '(5)' without using the function str((5))
Its not letting me post the question as my body is too short

Comment: That doesn't make any sense

Comment: wdym we use str to convert a integer to string right,i am just asking for a different method which does what str does

Comment: Because `str((5))` doesn't become `'(s)'`

Answer (score 2):

For example...

```
value = 5
string = f'{value}'
# '5'
```

if value is tuple then maybe..

```
value = (5,)
string = f'{value}'
# '(5,)'
```

unfortunately if tuple contains single element then result is '5'

```
value = (5)
string = f'{value}'
# '5'
```

but then you can do this

```
value = (5)
string = f'({value})'
# '(5)'
```

Comment: "if tuple contains single element then result is '5'" *no*, because that **isn't a tuple**